# Linux Server Hosting through Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, linux, server, hosting, proxy

I hosted a hobby NodeJS Server from my Linux and all is fine by accessing my direct IP.

Because I find this ugly and also less secure, I decided to route my domain which is set to Cloudflare to my IP. Then as I access the URL, I was prompted with an Authentication that I had never set up.

The question is, why proxy-ing through Cloudflare causes this? And how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I seem to find out the reason. It seems that my server is prompting Authentication whenever the port is not specified. Means Cloudflare is trying to redirect to my IP without the port. But would still need to know the best practice in this scenario and how to solve it.

**EDIT2:** I solved this by moving my port to 80. Since that is by default. But would pretty much still want to know if it is possible to get other ports to work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using some tool or service (here: CloudFlare). Such questions are on topic only if they cover how the tool integrates into some development *process* – after all, this site is about Software Engineering. See our [help/on-topic] for details. Please read: [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7253) Usage of development tools is on topic on Stack Overflow. For general purpose tools go to Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable the Cloudflare proxy service (cloud icon in the DNS configuration)

so Cloudflare will only work as a dns provider and not modify the traffic to your server.

Comment: won't this expose my IP? Or is this the only way to get it done?

Comment: yes, expose the ip, but i think is the only way

check https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169156-Which-ports-will-Cloudflare-work-with-